# How to setOnClickListener in adapter using RecyclerView to display inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I cannot access the ID of the item to view it in ToastMessage, or even store it in the database (use Room DataBase)
I have tried but the message does not appear
I need the reference ID to use for database storage and complete the process for storing the shopping cart

itemAdapter.java

```
public class itemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<itemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Items> arrayList;
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener;
    public itemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.desc.setText(arrayList.get(position).getItemDesc());
        holder.price.setText(arrayList.get(position).getItemPrice());
        holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,arrayList.get(position).getItemIid(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,arrayList.get(position).getItemPrice(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name, desc, price;
        ImageView remove, add;

        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        }
    }
   
}
```

MealsFragment.java

public class MealsFragment extends Fragment {

```
public MealsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

RecyclerView recyclerView;
itemAdapter adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meals, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated( View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<Items> ItemsList = (ArrayList<Items>) RoomDatabaseSingleton.getInstance(getContext().getApplicationContext())
            .getAppDatabase()
            .getDao()
            .getItems("meals");
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvMeals);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(
            getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    adapter = new itemAdapter(getContext(), ItemsList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Comment: In the constructor of your adapter try using `this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>(arrayList);` for initialization of the items arraylist.

Comment: The same problem

Comment: Can you please clarify your doubt a little bit more. So you're saying that when you click on the `add` Imageview, the toast is not showing?

Comment: @Khaled check the answer and see if it solves your issue

Comment: Your toasts don't have a `.show()` :)

Comment: its work ,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead

```
       holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,arrayList.get(position).getItemIid(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,arrayList.get(position).getItemPrice(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

The static method `makeText` of [`Toast`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts) is used to create the `Toast` object and [`show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#show()) method on the `Toast` object is used to display the Toast